# Branch Icon in Team Foundation Server 2010, can it be removed?

Tags: version-control, tfs, branch

recently I removed all branches from a TFS 2010 directory, making it standalone again, however it still has an icon showing that seems to indicate it's a parent to a branch.  Is there anyway to remove that icon and make it look like the rest of the folders?  This is with TFS 2010. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Select this folder in team explorer. Select File menu > source control > Branching and merging > convert to folder.

Regards